# If constructor has actions besides assignment should I move those actions in separate method?

Tags: java, constructor

I have class CellGroup that contains List of cell lists

That class has creation of list inside and transforming it to list of lists.

```
public class CellGroup {
    private List<List<Cell>> cells;

    public CellGroup(int predatorNumber, int preyNumber, int obstaclesNumber, int rowNum, int colNum){
        if (rowNum > 25 || colNum > 70) return;
        int totalCells = rowNum * colNum;
        List<Cell> cellList = IntStream.range(0, totalCells).mapToObj(i -> {
            if (i < predatorNumber) return new Predator(4, 4);
            if (i < predatorNumber + preyNumber) return new Prey(4);
            if (i < predatorNumber + preyNumber + obstaclesNumber) return new Obstacles();
            return new Cell();
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        Collections.shuffle(cellList);
        IntStream.range(0, totalCells).forEach(i -> cellList.get(i).setOceanCoordinate(new Point(i / colNum, i % colNum)));
        this.cells = ListUtils.partition(cellList, colNum);
    }
    public CellGroup(List<List<Cell>> cells) {

        this.cells = new ArrayList<>(cells);

    }

    public List<List<Cell>> getCells() {
        return cells;
    }

    public void setCells(List<List<Cell>> cells) {
        this.cells = cells;
    }


}
```

What is best approach to do it?

Comment: This post lacks contextual information for a proper code review. What is this class for, and how do other classes call and use this code?

Comment: A constructor should **not** have actions besides assignments in the first place.

Comment: There are different aspects. On one hand, doing serious work in a constructor typically is a bad idea. On the other hand, a constructor should deliver a fully-functioning object. So, with proper encapsulation in mind, you sometimes have to do some work in a constructor to transform its arguments into a consistent functional state of the instance.

Answer (score 1):

> I have class CellGroup that contains List of cell lists
>
> That class has creation of list inside and transforming it to list of lists.

I hate to tell you, but that is a lie. You actually have a CellGroup, that fills the list with some objects, shuffles the list, and transforms it to the list of lists and then saves it to the "cells" field.

What you would have to do is split the initialization from CellGroup.

```
public class CellGroup {
    private List<List<Cell>> cells;

    public CellGroup(List<List<Cell>> cells) {
        this.cells = new ArrayList<>(cells);
    }

    public List<List<Cell>> getCells() {
        return cells;
    }
}
```

```
public interface CellInitializer {
    List<List<Cell>> initialize(
        int predatorNumber,
        int preyNumber,
        int obstaclesNumber,
        int rowNum,
        int colNum
    );
}
```

```
public class MyCellInitializer implements CellInitializer {
    public List<List<Cell>> initialize(
        int predators,
        int prey,
        int obstacles,
        int rows,
        int columns
    ) {
        if (exceedesMaxMatrixSize(rows, columns)) return null;

        List<Cell> cellList = populateTheListWithCells(
            int predators,
            int prey,
            int obstacles,
            int rows,
            int columns
        );

        Collections.shuffle(cellList);
        assignOceanCoordinates(cellList, columns);

        return ListUtils.partition(cellList, columns);
    }

    private List<Cell> populateTheListWithCells(
        int predators,
        int prey,
        int obstacles,
        int rows,
        int columns
    ) {
        int totalCells = rows * columns;
        return IntStream.range(0, totalCells).mapToObj(i -> {
            if (i < predators) return new Predator(4, 4);
            if (i < predators + prey) return new Prey(4);
            if (i < predators + prey + obstacles) return new Obstacles();
            return new Cell();
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private void assignOceanCoordinates(List<Cell> cells, int columns) {
        for(int i = 0; i < cells.size(); i++) {
            cells.get(i).setOceanCoordinate(
                new Point(i / columns, i % columns)
            ));
        }
    }

    private boolean exceedesMaxMatrixSize(int rows, int columns) {
        retrun rows> 25 || columns > 70
    }
}
```

You could also make the initializer a "reset" method on CellGroup.